# Sealed data class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following sealed classes

```
sealed class DownloadWallpaper : Result() {
    data class Progress(val hd: Boolean = false, ...) : DownloadWallpaper() 
    data class Success(val hd: Boolean = false, ...) : DownloadWallpaper()
    data class Error(val hd: Boolean = false, ...) : DownloadWallpaper()
}
```

And I am trying to do the following.

```
//obs is of type Observable<Detail.Result.DownloadWallpaper> 
obs.map{ it.copy(hd = true) }
```

But I cant, for two reasons since `DownloadWallpaper` isn't a data class. There's not `.copy()` method. How can I tell Kotlin that all classes in this seal class are in fact `data classes`?

Secondly, `DownloadWallpaper` it self doesn't have an 'hd' field. I could cast this using when How can fix this elegantly?
This solution is quite ugly:

```
when (it) {
           is Detail.Result.DownloadWallpaper.Success -> it.copy(hd = true)
           is Detail.Result.DownloadWallpaper.Progress -> it.copy(hd = true)
           is Detail.Result.DownloadWallpaper.Error -> it.copy(hd = true)
 }
```

Comment: For the first, you can't, `copy` is auto-generated :/ `data class`es unfortunately tend to do badly with inheritance

Comment: Yup, that was what I was afraid of. I guess the proposed solution is not THAT bad, but I'll leave this question here in case someone comes up with a better solution

Comment: If you put your solution into a method of `DownloadWallpaper`, then you can reuse it everywhere

Answer (score 49, accepted):

By adding a few abstract methods to your sealed class I was able to access copy methods without explicit type check. See for yourself:

```
sealed class DownloadWallpaper {
    abstract val hd: Boolean
    abstract fun copy(hd: Boolean): DownloadWallpaper
}

data class Progress(override val hd: Boolean = false, val a: Any) : DownloadWallpaper() {
    override fun copy(hd: Boolean) = copy(hd = hd, a = a)
}
data class Success(override val hd: Boolean = false, val s: String) : DownloadWallpaper() {
    override fun copy(hd: Boolean) = copy(hd = hd, s = s)
}
data class Error(override val hd: Boolean = false, val c: Int) : DownloadWallpaper() {
    override fun copy(hd: Boolean) = copy(hd = hd, c = c)
}

fun main() {
    val dw: DownloadWallpaper = Progress()
    val newDw = dw.copy(hd = false)
    val newDwSameHd = dw.copy(hd = dw.hd)
}
```

Comment: It's a great and forgetten feature of sealed class. It contributes to decrease the boilerplate code due to the reduction of type casting. It should be default inside sealed classes, without demanding abstract classes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if kotlin provides a sealed data class too? Then we can omit write abstractions like this. Anyhow, this is a great solution where we want to have same variables but with different class names. We can get variables from these classes without casting is amazing 

Comment: This works great, except when one of your data classes has no extra parameters, then the abstract "copy" method collides with the generated copy method from the data class and cannot be overwritten due to recursive issues.