# How use all subclasses of a sealed class to handle a subclass instance?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to use the new `sealedSubclasses` feature in *Kotlin* in practice. I need to process a instance of some subclasses from a sealed class, but I don't kwow previously which subclass is, so the normal procedure is to try all subclasses.

Suppose that there are 20 or more subclasses.

Below, I simplified it a lot to make it easy to follow. I've used just 2 subclasses with  scalar internal types. In real world can be complex object types.

```
sealed class Person {
  abstract var name:String
     // ...
}

data class Doctor(      
  var license: String = "",   
    // ....
  override var name:String = ""
) : Person()

// ....
data class Fireman ( 
  var medals: Int=0, 
  // ....   
  override var name:String = ""
) : Person()
```

Now I need to clone that structure: First try:

```
var p:Person = Doctor("123","Louis")
var q:Person
  // ...
Person.copy  // it is forbidden
```

So I need to do

```
var p:Person = Doctor("123","Louis")
var q:Person
when (p) {
is Doctor -> q = p.copy()   
   // ...
is Fireman -> q = p.copy()
}
```

Notice that it is bad code, because always that I add a new subclass, I  have to add manually in clone process, repeating the sub block.

So I try to use `sealedSubclasses`, but I didn't get connect the subclass with a type in order to simulate the previous code

for (subClass in Token::class.sealedSubclasses) {
      if (ele::class.simpleName as String== derived.qualifiedName){
            // ??????
      }
  }

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

One solution to your problem would be to create your own implementation of the abstract `copy()` method:

```
sealed class Person {
    abstract val name: String
}

data class Doctor(
    override val name: String,
    val license: String,
    val extraProperty: Any
) : Person()

data class Fireman(
    override var name: String,
    val medals: Int
) : Person()

val p: Person = Doctor("123", "Louis", "extra")
var q: Person = when (p) {
    is Doctor -> p.copy(name = "New name", license = "Other license", extraProperty = "extra2")
    is Fireman -> p.copy(name = "New Name", medals = 15)
    // And so on...
}
```

Someone had a problem similar to yours in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/47624138/3542143

Comment: I've seen it before, but I think that It's a clumsy solution. I had to repeat  it in each sealed class that I've create in my conde.

Comment: You are right, it is repeatedly, to avoid it, I have updated the code, removing `abstract fun copy(name: String): Person` method since that  `when(p)` block infers the `Doctor` or `Fireman` type, so now we can use the default `copy` method. This works since I'm overriding name attribute and the own specific attributes of inherited classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you *can* do it by reflection, but I don't think `sealedSubclasses` will be useful. Approximately (untested):

```
fun copy(p: Person, name: String) {
   val copyMethod = p::class.memberFunctions().find { it.name == "copy" }!!
   val params = copyMethod.parameters
   val receiverParam = params[0]
   val nameParam = params.find { it.name == "name" }!!
   return copyMethod.callBy(mapOf(receiverParam to p, nameParam to name))
}
```

Of course, the normal caveats with reflection unsafety and performance apply.

Comment: Sincerily, Instead of getting into that kind of complexity, I'm almost preferring the bad solution to having to manually write all subclasses in my code, and putting a comment on the sealed class definition to never forget it.

Comment: In the kind of application I'm doing, which involves trees and graphs, sealed class helps me a lot. I couldn't give that up without my code getting messy. I use to make  generic nodes that can assume many analogous but not equal types. It's a kind of union type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics, I think, if you are using empty arguments for calling `copy()`. (On my phone, so please excuse any syntax issues here.)

```
class Person <out T: Person> {
    abstract var name: String
    abstract fun unchangedCopy(): T
}

data class Unemployed (
    override var name: String
): Person<Unemployed>() {
    override fun unchangedCopy() = copy()
}

var p:Person = Unemployed(“John”)
var q:Person = p.unchangedCopy()
```

This would force you to override `unchangedCopy` in each new subclass so there’s nothing to forget.

Comment: In the abstract class, I've tried to add 
`abstract fun <T>uCopy(p:T): T` 
And this code in a subclass
`override fun <Doctor>uCopy(p:Doctor ):Doctor = p.copy()`
But if gives a weird error in `copy` call, even is normally allowed in a data class.

Comment: If you use just   `fun uCopy(p:Doctor ):Doctor = p.copy()`, there is no error, but don't override nothing.